# creating decorated plaque for text

Tags: python

The output should be as follows:

Input:

```
Give the text: hippo

Give the character: x
```

Output:

```
xxxxxxx

xhippox

xxxxxxx
```

Input 2:

```
Give the text: sausage

Give the character: **
```

Output 2:

```
Invalid input! Type only one character!
```

The code im using:

```py
    text = input("Give the text: ")
    plaque = input("Give the character: ")

    def make_plaque(string):
        decorated = 'plaque' * (len(string) + 2) + "\n" #top row
        decorated = decorated + 'plaque' + string + "*\n" #middle row
        decorated = decorated + 'plaque' * (len(string) + 2) + "\n" #bottom row
        return decorated

    plaque = make_plaque(text)


    print(plaque)
```

Trying to make it work but still unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("Give the text: ")
char_check=False
while char_check is False:
    plaque = input("Give the character: ")
if len(plaque)>1:
    print("Invalid input! Type only one character!")
else:
    char_check=True

def make_plaque(string):
    decorated = plaque * (len(string) + 2) + "\n" #top row
    decorated = decorated + plaque + string + "{}\n".format(plaque) #middle row
    decorated = decorated + plaque * (len(string) + 2) +  "\n"#bottom row
return decorated

plaque = make_plaque(text)


print(plaque)
```

this code will do!

Comment: ***Error***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__tester__.python3", line 10, in <module>
    plaque = input("Give the character: ")
  File "__tester__.python3", line 3, in input
    s = __saved_input__(prompt)
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Answer (score 0):

You should really state your issue better. I assume the issue is that you don't have any error checking for your expected single character input. I would use a loop.

```py
not_valid = True
plaque_char = ""
while not_valid:
    plaque_char = input("Give the character: ")
    if len(plaque_char) != 1:
        print("Please enter one character.")
    else:
        not_valid = False
```

Using this code to manage the input of your plaque character should give you the desired error checking. However you can play with it to get it to detect multiple character or no characters if you want. I think; my syntax is good, but I've been using a lot of C++ lately, so if it is off sorry.